# How to use "Next!" on Rails for a loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

Salutations,

I'm a newbie learning the Rails (Ruby On Rails) program and I've came to a road block on one of the lessons. The assignment has me creating an odd numbers for the script to read starting from "18 to 0" using the "next" component. This is the example they've given me to change :

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end "
```

I wanted to know if I should the "next" to create a modulo that will begin with i leading to 0 or instead 18 ? It would be like this :

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 18 == 0
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

- T-Boye

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use next on ruby for this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840341/how-to-use-next-on-ruby-for-this-case)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what is the question? If the question is, how to skip even numbers, then you are almost there. You would do `% 2` instead of `% 18` though. If the question is "what does next do" you should look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) and scroll down to the `next` section.

Suggestion:

```
i = 19
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 1
  print i
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out now and see what happens

Comment: This is what I am putting for the next "i % 2 == 0 " would that be correct ?

Comment: This is the response the script gave me "191715131197531-1nil" . It said it looks like the loop didn't print out the variable of odd numbers

Comment: Put the `break if i <= 0` before the `print "#{i}"`

Comment: Ok, so I tried that variable you gave me, be the script gave me this "1817161514131211109876543210nil" and said it was incorrect .... "This what I wrote : i = 19
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 6
  break if i <= 0
  print "#{i}"
 end

Comment: What? Why would you change i = 20 to i = 19? Also i % 2 will never be anything other than 0 or 1? I'll put what I said in the answer.

Comment: I didn't know if changing the "i" to 19 would change the equation. Remember I'm still new to this, I'll try it out with 20

Comment: So I did it the way you told me: "i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i % 2 == 0
  break if i <= 0
  print "#{i}"
 end "
  and this is what the script gave me "191715131197531nil"

Comment: What is the output that you want? Because that right there is every odd from 19 to 1.

Comment: This is the instructions for the problem "Change your loop using the next keyword so that it skips printing odd numbers." That's it, they aren't telling me whether how many odd numbers or how the line should be

Comment: Try what I put in the answer.