# how to use next on ruby for this case?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby On Rails program and I've came to a road block on one of the lessons. The assignment has me creating an odd numbers for the script to read starting from "20 to 0" using the `next` component. This is the example they've given me to change :

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

This is the problem:

> Add a line to your loop before your print statement. Use the `next` keyword so that you skip to the next iteration if the number i is odd.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Kind of strange how the first half of your question matches this one almost word for word: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263460/how-to-use-next-on-rails-for-a-loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just insert a `next` that skips the rest of the loop if the number is odd:

```
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i.odd?
  puts "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Comment: i keep getting this message try again. It looks like your loop doesn't print out the numbers 18 to 0.  am i Missing something ?

Comment: I just copied your code, but I don’t know why it uses `print` when I’d expect it to use `puts`.

Comment: Good to hear. If you accept the answer, other people will see that you don’t need an answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way:

```ruby
i = 20
loop do
  i -= 1
  next if i%2 != 0
  print "#{i}"
  break if i <= 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 20
loop do
i -= 1
next if i % 2 == 0
print "#{i}"
break if i <=1
end
```